# Integrate flask-sqlalchemy into project

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-restful

I am new comer of flask api. I am doing a flask restful api project which purpose is to search stores by store name that is kept in existing database online. 
Now is is connect to database using `psycopg2`. 
I would like to improve it by using `flask-sqlalchemy`. I have searched on the web and the solution seems to use [Automap](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/extensions/automap.html), that I learned from the [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UK57IHzSh8I&list=PLXmMXHVSvS-BlLA5beNJojJLlpE0PJgCW&index=26). The problem I am facing now is how to integrate those codes into my existing project, like where should I put the settings like `automap_base()`  into my existing codes. Here is my current file structure:

```
app.py
  ∟ models
    ∟ family_mart.py
  ∟ resources
    ∟ family_mart.py
```

**app.py**:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Api

from resources.family_mart import FamilyMart

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'apple'
api = Api(app)


api.add_resource(FamilyMart, '/familymart/<string:name>')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=5000, debug=True)
```

**family_mart.py** in **models** folder:

```
import psycopg2
from config import config

class FamilyMartModel:
    @classmethod
    def find_by_name(cls, name):
        conn = None
        try:
            params = config()

            conn = psycopg2.connect(**params)
            cur = conn.cursor()

            query = f"""
                SELECT extract_date
                       , store_name
                       , address
                FROM cnvnt_str_fm
                WHERE store_name = '{name}'
            """
            cur.execute(query)

            rows = cur.fetchall()
            cur.close()

            if rows:
                result = {'store':[]}
                for row in rows:
                    append_dict = {'extract_date':row[0].strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),
                                   'store_name':row[1],
                                   'address':row[2]}
                    result['store'].append(append_dict)
                return result

        except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
            print(error)

        finally:
            if conn is not None:
                conn.close()
                print('Database connection closed.')
```

**family_mart.py** in **resources** folder:

```
from flask_restful import Resource

from models.family_mart import FamilyMartModel


class FamilyMart(Resource):
    def get(self, name):
        item = FamilyMartModel.find_by_name(name)
        if item:
            return item
        return {'message':'Store not found.'}, 404
```

Answer (score 0):

After study the [documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/tutorial.html), I restructured my project and integrate with `sqlalchemy` successfully. I removed `model` folder and added `db.py` to configure the existing database, here is the detail :
New file structure:

```
app.py
  ∟ resources
    ∟ family_mart.py
db.py
```

**app.py**:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Api

from config import config
from db import db
from resources.family_mart import FamilyMart

params = config()
DB_FULL_URL = f"postgresql+psycopg2://{params['user']}:{params['password']}@{params['host']}/{params['database']}"


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = DB_FULL_URL
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
app.secret_key = 'apple'

api = Api(app)


api.add_resource(FamilyMart, '/familymart/<string:name>')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    db.init_app(app)
    app.run(port=5000, debug=True)
```

**db.py**:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy import MetaData
from sqlalchemy import Table, Column, Integer, String, DateTime

db = SQLAlchemy()

metadata_obj = MetaData()

fm_table = Table('cnvnt_str_fm', metadata_obj,
    Column('extract_date', String),
    Column('store_name', String),
    Column('address', String)                
)
```

**family_mart.py**:

```
from flask_restful import Resource

from db import db
from db import fm_table


class FamilyMart(Resource):
    def get(self, name):
        results = db.session.query(fm_table).filter_by(store_name=name).\
            order_by(fm_table.c.extract_date.desc()).limit(3)
        
        output = {'store':[]}
        
        for row in results:
            extract_date = str(row[0])
            store_name = row[1]
            address = row[2]
            output['store'].append({'extract_date':extract_date,
                'store_name':store_name, 
                'address':address})
        return output
```